# Can't create meteor project

Tags: meteor

I had a problem where I couldn't create a meteor project using the following command:

```
cd c:/projects
meteor create foo
```

I got this error:

```
You can't create a Meteor project inside another Meteor project.
```

I found some answers for this problem saying there could me a .meteor folder in the projects folder, but this was not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out there was a .meteor folder in my c:/. After removing this folder the command create worked again.